# Visualforce Function Error on ActivityHistory.Description field

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to display the Description (Comments) field on a Task in a Visualforce page, but the field is too long for the column in which I'm displaying it. So, I tried to use the [`LEFT`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) Visualforce function to get the leftmost 100 characters.

However, I'm receiving this error:

```
Save error: Syntax Error. Missing ')'
```

Here's my Visualforce Markup. `Activities` is of type [ActivityHistory](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm).

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!Activities}" var="activity" style="width:100%;">
  <apex:column value="{!activity.OwnerId}" headervalue="Name (Assigned)" />
  <apex:column value="{!activity.WhoId}" headervalue="Contact" />
  <apex:column value="{!LEFT(activity.Description, 100)}" headervalue="Comments" />
  <apex:column value="{!activity.ActivityDate}" headervalue="Date" />
</apex:pageblocktable>
```

While the *above* does not work, when I change the `<apex:column>` to this (*below*) it does work but it doesn't accomplish what I'd like to.

```
<apex:column value="{!activity.Description}" headervalue="Comments" />
```

Why is this error occurring, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `<apex:column>` component does not allow (at least some) Visualforce formulas in its value attribute. I got this to work by using an `<apex:outputtext>` component inside of the `<apex:column>`.

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!Activities}" var="activity" style="width:100%;">
  <apex:column value="{!activity.OwnerId}" headervalue="Name (Assigned)" />
  <apex:column value="{!activity.WhoId}" headervalue="Contact" />
  <apex:column headervalue="Comments">
    <apex:outputtext value="{!LEFT(activity.Description, 100)}" />
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column value="{!activity.ActivityDate}" headervalue="Date" />
</apex:pageblocktable>
```